# How to select data from an entire column and present it as separate choices in a select tag.

Tags: php, sql, html

I think this question is going to be rather interesting. So, as the title suggests, I am trying to make a dynamic `select` field. Basically, when the time comes my web app will connect to my database, and pull the entire row that matches my query. My question is this: How can I present the data from ONE of the columns within the row as INDIVIDUAL options within the `select` tag? This is what I am trying right now:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $servername = "127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "people";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }else{
            $search_query = "SELECT * FROM people_list WHERE person_id = $_SESSION[person_id]";
            $result = $conn->query($search_query);
            while($person_result_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "

            <option value='$result[person_result_list]'>'$result[person_name]', '$result[person_result_list]'</option>

            ";



            }

        }

    ?>
    </select>
```

This is returning an error:
`Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`
Which should be pretty straight forward to fix, but I just can't figure out the workaround to this. Any ideas?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

That's because of this statement,

```
<option value='$result[person_result_list]'>'$result[person_name]', '$result[person_result_list]'</option>
               ^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^
```

`$result` is a `MySQLi` result object, not an array.

> My question is this: How can I present the data from ONE of the columns within the row as INDIVIDUAL options within the select tag?

Simply fetch the row the result set and use `foreach` loop to display each individual column value inside `<option>` element, like this:

```
// your code

$search_query = "SELECT * FROM people_list WHERE person_id = $_SESSION[person_id]";
$result = $conn->query($search_query);
$person_result_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
foreach($person_result_list as $value){
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>'
}

// your code
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use GROUP_CONCAT in the query. It will return you a comma separated string of the values of your target column only. You then can split this string to make it an array to use for the select dropdown.